# where does the object/database mapping belong?

Tags: c#, database, mapping, data-access-layer, dto

I'm currently working on a project where we are using a lightweight DataAccessLayer. The project consists of a businesslayer,a dataacesslayer and a project which holds the DTOs. This setup is fix and I cannot change. Neither can I use a full fledged ORM like Nhibernate or Entity Framework.

ok, to properly work with this setup we need to somehow map our DTO's properties to the fields of the database. Currently we are doing this in the dataaccesslayer (every entity/DTO "possesses" a dataaccesslayer-class).
This happens in two methods MapTo and MapFrom: the first maps the object's fields to the table's fields and the other does the reverse.

Now I'm wondering if the dataaccesslayer is the correct place to define this mapping. Wouldn't it be better to define the mapping in the DTO's. For example with attributes?
Or better a more generic method instead of a method for every class which basically just maps properties to table fields.

Answer (score 0):

You mean domain model by DTO, right? Typically, the mapping between entities and tables belongs to data access layer. But I wouldn't put the mapping into domain model project. In that case, for example, when your DB table changes, then you have to change/compile domain model as well as DAL. In other example, if you have the mapping in DAL, when you switch database or ORM method, you can  achieve that with only change of DAL.